# Java "mob" class

Tags: java, frameworks

I haven't been able to find the solution to my troubles yet, so thought I'd ask this always helpful forum.

I'm creating some framework to what should end up as a "tower defence"-game, but as a newbie at Java, and programming in general, I'm not sure how the idea behind my "mob class" should work.
Could it be done by Extends JLabel? Or Extends Jpanel? 
If there's gonna spawn 100 mobs, is one preffered over the other?
Should I instead of instantiating a new JLabel/JPanel everytime a mobs spawns, perhaps just draw in the "level" class - paintComponent function ?

Hope I wont get flamed for asking for help before trying, but as a beginner, I hope not to rewrite everything of my framework logic in a couple of days.
Any pointers and help in general is appreciated!

Edit: Mob is an easy to kill "monster", but usually comes in large groups.
In a Tower Defense Game, mobs follows a path, while towers shoots them down before the reach finish.

Comment: First of all, what is a *mob class*?

Comment: You should separate the logic from the presentation. There should be a "Mob" class that just has all of the data and the logic for the mobs and then there should be a separate class for displaying mobs.

Comment: Mob should be a simple model with coordinates and health, maybe type. Then there is a presentation/renderer and another one is a logic that decides over moves of a single mob or a group of mobs, knowing the game board/map

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to try with Extends JButton, and see where that takes me.

Comment: Why is that? Because there is `Action` method? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for JLabel (if the mob is just an image) or JPanel if the mob is a composition of different items.